# How move/copy files work in OS?

Tags: file-management, file-transfer

As the title asks, how in detail do they work? This question is often on my mind because I could not find a good article that explains how it works in detail. The questions is:

1. How does the OS actually move / copy a file?
2. Why does a file move go faster than a file copy?

If someone explain the answer in detail, maybe this question can serve as a reference in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without going into any detail about how the various filesystems are laid out, when the OS copies a file, a new file is actually created in the destination directory, and the contents of the source file are read and then written to that new file.

When a file is moved to a different location on the same filesystem, the data stays in the same place, and the metadata that points to that location is simply updated. This is why it takes so little time - the actual contents of the file aren't being moved.

For more in-depth technical information, you can look at documentation for the actual file systems - this will tell you how the data is actually read and written. For example, [ext2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2#ext2_data_structures).

Answer (score -2):

1. Moving a file is essentially copying it to another location and then deleting the original. Copying is the same as above, except the original isn't deleted.
2. Moving a file is actually a bit slower then copying a file since it has to delete the original.

Hope this helps. :D

Comment: I don't think that's true. I think that cutting a file just changes the pointers on the OS. You can cut a multiple GB file that's on the same drive in a few seconds. Copying it takes hours.

Comment: Often a move is just a transfer of dentries; as long as you're on the same filesystem, moves are faster.